# Mysql query for 3 tables & user meta

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join, meta

I am attempting to create a mysql query to join 3 tables of data into a single row. However I am having some issues due to the way the user meta table is laid out. The tables structure is as follows:

**users**

```
id       user_login       user_registered

1        user1            18/06/2018
2        user2            18/06/2018
```

**usermeta**

```
user_id       meta_key       meta_value

1             color          blue
1             type           train
2             color          red
2             type           car
```

**member_subscription**

```
user_id       status

1             active  
2             active
```

I want to select the user_login of each user by today's date only on user_registered and join their id's with the user_id of both the usermeta table and member_subscription table but only where the status in the member_subscription table is = 'active', and also include relevant meta data to each user as well so I end up with the following:

```
user_login     color      type

user1          blue       train
user2          red        car
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as i'm really struggling with this one.

Comment: What parts have you been able to do & what did you get stuck on? Please read & act on [ask] & [mcve], also hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [Entity–attribute–value model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) aka EAV structure to list attributes in different columns you can use conditional aggregation based on your attributes by joining your meta table like

```
SELECT u.id, 
       u.user_login, 
       MAX(CASE 
             WHEN m.meta_key = 'color' THEN m.meta_value 
             ELSE NULL 
           END) AS color, 
       MAX(CASE 
             WHEN m.meta_key = 'type' THEN m.meta_value 
             ELSE NULL 
           END) AS type 
FROM   users u 
       JOIN usermeta m 
         ON m.user_id = u.id 
       JOIN member_subscription ms 
         ON ms.user_id = u.id 
WHERE  ms.status = 'active' 
GROUP  BY u.id, 
          u.user_login
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f8188/4)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way, but if you join the table twice it would make it easy to filter out based on your necessary conditions. Something like:

```
SELECT u.user_login, um1.meta_value AS color, um2.meta_value AS type
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN usermeta um1 
     ON um1.user_id=u.id
     AND um1.meta_key='color'
LEFT JOIN usermeta um2 
     ON um2.user_id=u.id
     AND um2.meta_key='type'
JOIN member_subscription ms 
     ON ms.user_id=u.id
WHERE ms.status='active'
```